# Xamarin Forms delete from sqlite database

Tags: c#, linq, sqlite, xamarin.forms

I have a class Announcement, and I have a list of id, I am using the nuget package: sqlite-net-pcl.
How can I delete an announcement from my Announcement table if I have it id. I am trynig to use linq like: await connection.DeleteAsync(announcement).Where(...)
but I can't use Where with the DeleteAsync, so I tried

```
var query = connection.Table<Announcement>().Where(announcement=>announcement.AnnouncementId == announcementId)
```

it gives me this erro :System.NotSupportedException: Cannot delete AsyncTableQuery`1: it has no PK

Comment: try to get the **FirstOrDefault()** value. here in your case the query contains a list of items (but imho this list just contains one single item). maby this will fix your problem

Comment: I get this error: Cannot assign method group to an implicitly-typed variable, and I added await so i get: Cannot await 'method group'

Comment: where do you my FirstOrDefault?

Answer (score 9):

I think you are looking for something like this:

```
public static int Delete(string url)
{
    using (var databaseManager = DatabaseManager.Instance)
    {
        lock (databaseManager)
        {
            return databaseManager.Database.Table<File>().Delete(x => x.Url == url);
        }
    }
}
```

This is `using SQLite;`
https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/data-and-cloud-services/data-access/part-3-using-sqlite-orm/

Answer (score 1):

I have never used the nuget in question but I have had a quick look on the source and it would appear that `TableQuery` has a sync method called `Delete` that returns an integer.

The code you have included above is returning an object of type `TableQuery<Announcement>`. The class TableQuery contains the following definition:

```
public int Delete(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predExpr)
{
    if (predExpr.NodeType == ExpressionType.Lambda) {
        var lambda = (LambdaExpression)predExpr;
        var pred = lambda.Body;
        var args = new List<object> ();
        var w = CompileExpr (pred, args);
        var cmdText = "delete from \"" + Table.TableName + "\"";
        cmdText += " where " + w.CommandText;
        var command = Connection.CreateCommand (cmdText, args.ToArray ());

        int result = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        return result;
    } else {
        throw new NotSupportedException ("Must be a predicate");
    }
}
```

It would seem that you should just use the following:

```
connection.Table<Announcement>().Delete(announcement=>announcement.AnnouncementId == announcementId)
```

This code is completely untested and is from reviewing the source code of the nuget package on Github (https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net/blob/master/src/SQLite.cs).

Comment: 'AsyncTableQuery<Announcement>' does not contain a definition for 'Delete' and no extension method 'Delete' accepting a first argument of type 'AsyncTableQuery<Announcement>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: TableQuery definitely has a definition for Delete - see the code snippet in the answer that is taken directly from the source. Follow the link above. If you are still having problems add more information and I will take a look

Answer (score 0):

Have your ID Property the Primary Key Attribute ?

```
[PrimaryKey,AutoIncrement]
public int Id { get; set; }
```

Comment: Yes :[PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
        public int AnnouncementId { get; set; }